# How would I open my modal with by clicking a button using redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I want to open my modal using redux by clicking `<CheckoutButton/>` but it still keeps appearing upon reloading my browser.  I can't see what I'm doing wrong in my code.  What am I doing wrong and how would I go about fixing this?  If additional code is needed, I'll prove it upon request.

Here's `TacoTypes.js` code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import FoodButton from '../../components/FoodButton/FoodButton';
import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import CheckoutButton from '../../containers/CheckoutButton/CheckoutButton';
import Modal from '../../components/Modal/Modal';
import * as actionType from '../../store/actions';

class TacoTypes extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Aux>    
                <CheckoutButton clicked={() => this.props.openModalRedux()}/>

                <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}/>
            </Aux>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        isOpen: state.isOpen.isModalOpen
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        openModalRedux: () => dispatch({type: actionType.OPEN_MODAL})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TacoTypes);
```

Here's `global.js` (reducer) file:

```
import * as actionType from '../store/actions';

const initialState = {
    isModalOpen: false
};

const global = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.OPEN_MODAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isModalOpen: true
            }

        case actionType.CLOSE_MODAL:
            return {
                ...state,
                isModalOpen: false
            }
    }
    return state
};

export default global;
```

Here's `Modal.js` code:

```
import React from 'react';
import classes from './Modal.css';

const modal = (props) => {
    return(
        <div onClick={props.isOpen} className={classes.Modal}>
            <h1>modal</h1>
            <button>dismiss</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default modal;
```

Comment: Where do you dispatch `CLOSE_MODAL`?

Comment: @Colin Didn't use it yet, I just want to get OPEN_MODAL to work first

Comment: <Modal isOpen={false}/> is always false, is that right? shouldn't it be <Modal isOpen={this.props.isOpen}/> ?

Comment: @fnaquira correct.  I've tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: <div onClick={props.isOpen} className={classes.Modal}> does not show any change of behavior, is onClick correct? shouldn't you change the styles or classes to show or hide the modal?

Comment: @fnaquira I thought what I have so far would at least show the modal upon clicking on the button but it doesn't.

Comment: To show modal when button is clicked. Trigger a Redux action with Boolean value true on button click >> In reducer based on action type set the state>> get the state in the component where you want to show the modal >> show the modal when this state is true >> now at the same time you should make it false in order for its to work the second time when you click button >> so call the action on modal closing by passing false value. That’s all

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you are not telling your Modal component to show or hide, you should do that in order to make it work, something like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import classes from './Modal.css';
import Aux from '../../../hoc/Auxiliary/Auxiliary';
import Backdrop from '../Backdrop/Backdrop';

class Modal extends Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps, nextState ) {
        return nextProps.show !== this.props.show || nextProps.children !== this.props.children;
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Backdrop show={this.props.show} clicked={this.props.modalClosed} />
                <div
                    className={classes.Modal}
                    style={{
                        transform: this.props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                        opacity: this.props.show ? '1' : '0'
                    }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

export default Modal;
```